# How to update MLLIB version in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I have installed Cloudera VM and hence it has PySpark with MLLIB library, but the ML library *MLLIB* is too old, I just wanted to upgrade it with latest version of MLLIB, Already updated the python from 2.6 to 2.7, but unable to find any documentation to upgrade *MLLIB*.

Thanks

Krishna

Answer (score 3):

Different Spark components are tightly connected and in general are not compatible between versions so you should simply update complete Spark distribution. [Spark Downloads page](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) provides a number of binaries pre-built with different Hadoop versions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if possible can you please provide how should I update completed Spark distribution.

Comment: Go to the linked download page, choose desired binaries, download, unpack. Optionally copy existing configuration.

Comment: I have put some instructions on how to "upgrade" Spark here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887227/how-to-upgrade-spark-to-newer-version/33914992#33914992