# Running pyspark after pip install pyspark

Tags: pip, pyspark

I wanted to install `pyspark` on my home machine. I did

```
pip install pyspark
pip install jupyter
```

Both seemed to work well.

But when I try to run `pyspark` I get

```
pyspark
Could not find valid SPARK_HOME while searching ['/home/user', '/home/user/.local/bin']
```

What should `SPARK_HOME` be set to?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I just faced the same issue, but it turned out that `pip install pyspark` downloads spark distirbution that works well in local mode. Pip just doesn't set appropriate `SPARK_HOME`. But when I set this manually, pyspark works like a charm (without downloading any additional packages).

```
$ pip3 install --user pyspark
Collecting pyspark
  Downloading pyspark-2.3.0.tar.gz (211.9MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 211.9MB 9.4kB/s 
Collecting py4j==0.10.6 (from pyspark)
  Downloading py4j-0.10.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (189kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 194kB 3.9MB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: pyspark
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyspark ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/mario/.cache/pip/wheels/4f/39/ba/b4cb0280c568ed31b63dcfa0c6275f2ffe225eeff95ba198d6
Successfully built pyspark
Installing collected packages: py4j, pyspark
Successfully installed py4j-0.10.6 pyspark-2.3.0

$ PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3 SPARK_HOME=~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyspark pyspark
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
2018-03-31 14:02:39 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.0
      /_/

Using Python version 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017 16:37:01)
>>>
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. As I was using virtual environment, I had to do it following way: 
PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3 
SPARK_HOME=~/Users/"myname"/virtualenvs/"env_name"/lib/python(folder name)/site-packages/pyspark

Comment: Not working for me, I cannot avoid "Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o25.isBarrier. Trace: py4j.Py4JException: Method isBarrier([]) does not exist"

Answer (score 13):

Pyspark from PyPi (i.e. installed with `pip`) does not contain the full Pyspark functionality; it is only intended for use with a Spark installation in an already existing cluster [EDIT: or in local mode only - see accepted answer]. From the [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyspark/2.2.0):

> The Python packaging for Spark is not intended to replace all of the other use cases. This Python packaged version of Spark is suitable for interacting with an existing cluster (be it Spark standalone, YARN, or Mesos) - but does not contain the tools required to setup your own standalone Spark cluster. You can download the full version of Spark from the Apache Spark downloads page.
>
> **NOTE**: If you are using this with a Spark standalone cluster you must
>   ensure that the version (including minor version) matches or you may
>   experience odd errors

You should download a full Spark distribution as described [here](https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html).

Comment: @eleanora you just download, unzip, and set `SPARK_HOME` - see my answer on 'upgrading' here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887227/how-to-upgrade-spark-to-newer-version/33914992#33914992 , but the web is literally full of such step-by-step tutorials...

Answer (score 2):

To install Spark, make sure you have Java 8 or higher installed. Then go to [Spark Downloads](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) page to select latest spark release, prebuilt package for Hadoop and download it. Unzip the file and move to your /opt (or for that matter any folder, but remember where you moved it)

```
mv spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7 /opt/spark-2.4.4
```

Then create a symbolic link. This way you can download and use multiple spark versions.

```
ln -s /opt/spark-2.4.4 /opt/spark
```

Add the following to your, `.bash_profile` to tell your bash where to find Spark.

```
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Finally, to setup Spark to use python3, please add the following to /opt/spark/conf/spark-env.sh file

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in python 3.0+ 
then open anaconda prompt
execute the below command
**pip3 install --user pyspark**

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do take a minute to see how to properly format your code

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way - Open anaconda prompt and type pip install --user pyspark / pip3 install --user pyspark