# Installing pyspark on MacBook

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, homebrew

I have used Spark in Scala for a long time. Now I am using pyspark for the first time. This is on a Mac

1. First I installed pyspark using conda install pyspark, and it installed pyspark 2.2.0
2. I installed spark itself using brew install apache-spark, and it seems to have installed apache-spark 2.2.0

but when I run pyspark, it dumps out

```
/Users/me/anaconda/bin/pyspark: line 24: /Users/bruceho/spark-1.6/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/load-spark-env.sh: No such file or directory
/Users/me/anaconda/bin/pyspark: line 77: /Users/bruceho/spark-1.6/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory
/Users/me/anaconda/bin/pyspark: line 77: exec: /Users/bruceho/spark-1.6/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit: cannot execute: No such file
```

Why is it pointing to the 1.6.2 installation, which seems to be no longer there? Brew search apache-spark does indicate the presence of both 1.5. and 1.6. Shouldn't pyspark 2.2.0 automatically point to the apache-spark 2.2.0 installation?

Comment: Did you set up `SPARK_HOME`, `PYSPARK_PYTHON`, `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` in `.bash_profile`?

Comment: I found an old SPARK_HOME left over in .bash_profile. No need to define these parameters when using brew install apache-spark.

Comment: Probably just need to remove it, I guess?

Comment: I did, and its running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a number of issues with your question:

To start with, PySpark is **not** an add-on package, but an essential component of Spark itself; in other words, when installing Spark you get also PySpark by default (you cannot avoid it, even if you would like to). So, step 2 should be enough (and even before that, PySpark should be available in your machine since you have been using Spark already).

Step 1 is unnecessary: Pyspark from PyPi (i.e. installed with `pip` or `conda`) does not contain the full Pyspark functionality; it is only intended for use with a Spark installation in an already existing cluster. From the [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyspark):

> The Python packaging for Spark is not intended to replace all of the other use cases. This Python packaged version of Spark is suitable
>   for interacting with an existing cluster (be it Spark standalone,
>   YARN, or Mesos) - but does not contain the tools required to setup
>   your own standalone Spark cluster. You can download the full version
>   of Spark from the Apache Spark downloads page.
>
> **NOTE**: If you are using this with a Spark standalone cluster you must ensure that the version (including minor version) matches or you
>   may experience odd errors

Based on the fact that, as you say, you have already been using Spark (via Scala), your issue seems rather to be about upgrading. Now, if you use pre-built Spark distributions, you have actually nothing to install - you just download, unzip, and set the relevant environment variables (`SPARK_HOME` etc) - see my answer on ["upgrading" Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887227/how-to-upgrade-spark-to-newer-version/33914992#33914992), which is actually also applicable for first-time "installations".

Comment: I guess I did not make it clear. After removing old SPARK_HOME declarations in .bash_profile, everything is running. I have seen several documentations on installing Spark. Using homebrew is the by far the simplest, which is what I used. I already know the need for spark installation on top of pyspark. Like I said I installed the latest spark using brew.

Comment: Indeed you did not, but anyway, hopefully you have learned something new (i.e. that step 1 is unnecessary)

Comment: I believe you can skip step 1 if you only use spark-submit. however, quite often, you would like to just run the spark code locally using python, in which case, you would want to have pyspark available to import.

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1:** If you don't have brew first install brew using the following command in terminal

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

**Step 2:** Once you have brew then run below command to install java on your Mac.

```
brew cask install homebrew/cask-versions/adoptopenjdk8
```

**Step 3:** Once Java is installed run the below command to install spark on Mac

```
brew install apache-spark
```

**Step 4:** type `pyspark -version`

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to install `pyspark` right now would to do a pip install with version > 2.2.

```
pip install pyspark
```

If you want to use a distribution instead (and want to use `jupyter` along with it), another way would be:
https://blog.sicara.com/get-started-pyspark-jupyter-guide-tutorial-ae2fe84f594f